# Max and min values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, max, min

I have the following data:

```
High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
1999-12-31  1472.420044 1458.189941 1464.469971 1469.250000 374050000   1469.250000
2000-01-03  1478.000000 1438.359985 1469.250000 1455.219971 931800000   1455.219971
2000-01-04  1455.219971 1397.430054 1455.219971 1399.420044 1009000000  1399.420044
2000-01-05  1413.270020 1377.680054 1399.420044 1402.109985 1085500000  1402.109985
2000-01-06  1411.900024 1392.099976 1402.109985 1403.449951 1092300000  1403.449951
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-01-06  3246.840088 3214.639893 3217.550049 3246.280029 3674070000  3246.280029
2020-01-07  3244.909912 3232.429932 3241.860107 3237.179932 3420380000  3237.179932
2020-01-08  3267.070068 3236.669922 3238.590088 3253.050049 3720890000  3253.050049
2020-01-09  3275.580078 3263.669922 3266.030029 3274.699951 3638390000  3274.699951
2020-01-10  3282.989990 3268.010010 3281.810059 3273.739990 920449258   3273.739990
5039 rows × 6 columns
```

Since this is the daily data this was resampled to weekly to find the 52 week high and low.

```
weekly_high = data.High.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).tail(52)
weekly_low = data.Low.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).tail(52)
```

Here is the problem:

```
weekly_high.max()
```

yields: 3282.989990234375

```
weekly_low.min()
```

yeilds: 666.7899780273438

These value are are issue because 3283.0 is the high so why am i getting in deimals? Secondly weekly low is is 666 which i know for a fact is incorrect. How can i fix this?

Comment: You are calculating the max and min based on the last 52 rows

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Sorry. Is it possible that the min and max are not part of the last 52 rows? When you created `weekly_high` and `weekly_low`, you are taking only the last 52 rows, because you have `.tail(52)`. If the min and max that you are looking for are outside of those rows, then surely you will not find them when you are looking for the max value of the last 52 rows.

Comment: You are right! i guess .tail(52) just shows you and does not actually slice. The length is `Length: 5039`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you can try the following code:

```
data['52weekhigh'] = data.High.rolling(252).max()
data['52weeklow'] = data.Low.rolling(252).min()
```

This allows you to prevent having to resample on a monthly basis and gives you the rolling 52 week high (52 weeks == 252 trading days) Let me know if you need any further clarification.